# Moving the main content Wordpress Constructor

Tags: css, wordpress, layout, constructor

I am trying to move my main content roughly 10 pixels over to the left using the constructor theme and I have no idea how I would do this, I tried doing things like reducing the width in the layout tab and increasing the size of the content but it won't move over the position that it is in now does anyone know how I can do this, thanks

EDIT: I have tried searching for the answers to this on things like the constructor themes FAQs and on the wordpress forums but no luck

EDIT 2: I should mention the reason I am trying to move it over 10 pixels is to line it up with the edge of the header

Comment: Have you tried adding

Margin-left: 10px;

to the css for the container?

Comment: Will that cause the header and the content to move by 10 pixels though or just the content

Comment: if built properly it should move everything within it as well

Comment: it sounds like there's padding on a parent element pushing it right, but without seeing the code, that's just a guess. can you post a sample or a link to the page?

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to your "constructor theme's" css doc. by selecting it under wordpress dashboard-Appearance-Editor. Once you have the css find the ID #wrapcontent and the Class .wrapper and add "margin-left: 10px;" to the .wrapper class.